What mathematical terminology and equations are used for variant assertions of finite sets?
Below there is a set of variants (or enumerations) of multiple finite sets with a different number of items in each set.
I don't want to use the word combinations because I believe those are of the same finite set--repeating items can be important with those and order too can be important with those.
Would this be a logical matrix of some kind?  Or some other term in set theory?
I can easily get the enumerations by having four loops in a program and simply iterate through them, because this is a very common tactic used in programming to create struct variables for getting results.  We simply have four sets, and we iterate through them in order.  But what is the mathematical term for figuring this out using a pattern (in the proper notation(s)--like set theory), so if I ever need to present the concept, I would be using the correct mathematical terms, and using variables rather than numbers below?  And how is order of items and repeating of items expressed here?
Feel free to correct my tags as well...
Let's take four finite sets to keep it simple.  We will have $7 * 4 * 3 * 2 = 168$ variants here
color      shape       material       outcome
-----      -----       --------       ------
red        triangle    titanium       true
orange     square      aluminum       false
yellow     pentagon    ABS  
green      hexagon
blue
indigo
violet

The variants would look something like this.
color      shape         material       outcome
-----      -----         --------       ------
red        triangle      titanium       true
red        triangle      titanium       false
red        triangle      aluminum       true
red        triangle      aluminum       false
red        triangle      ABS            true
red        triangle      ABS            false

red        square        titanium       true
red        square        titanium       false
red        square        aluminum       true
red        square        aluminum       false
red        square        ABS            true
red        square        ABS            false

red        pentagon      titanium       true
red        pentagon      titanium       false
red        pentagon      aluminum       true
red        pentagon      aluminum       false
red        pentagon      ABS            true
red        pentagon      ABS            false

red        hexagon       titanium       true
red        hexagon       titanium       false
red        hexagon       aluminum       true
red        hexagon       aluminum       false
red        hexagon       ABS            true
red        hexagon       ABS            false

... then repeat for each color

Cartesian product

That is the Cartesian Cross Product.
$A \times B = \{(x,y): x \in A , y \in B\}$
$A \times B \times C = \{(x,y,z): x \in A , y \in B , z \in C\}$
Like-wise , we have $A \times B \times C \times D$
Elaborate Example which OP requested :
Let $A=\{red , blue , green , yellow\}$ , $B=\{triangle , hexagon\}$ , $C=\{titanium\}$
What $A \times B$ means is that , we take 1 element from $A$ (eg red) ,  1 element from $B$ (eg triangle) , to make a Pair $(red , triangle)$ which we put in new Set P , which we write like $P = A \times B$. We move to next element in $B$. When we use all elements in $B$ , we move to next element in $A$ & start with first element of $B$.
Just like the "for loop" in Computer Programming.
We will end up with $P= A \times B = \{ (red , triangle) , (red ,hexagon) , (blue , triangle) , (blue , hexagon) , \cdots (green , triangle ), \cdots ( yellow , hexagon ) \}$ , having $4 \times 2 = 8$ elements
When we try with $A \times B \times C$ , we will have only 1 element to choose from $C$ in that "for loop" , hence all triplets will be like $(green,hexagon,titanium)$ or $(x,y,titanium)$ , for various $x$ & $y$.
We will end up with $P= A \times B \times C = \{ (red , triangle , titanium) , (red ,hexagon , titanium) , (blue , triangle , titanium) , (blue , hexagon , titanium) , \cdots (green , triangle , titanium), \cdots ( yellow , hexagon , titanium) \}$ , having $4 \times 2 \times 1 = 8$ elements
When $D = \{ \}$ , we will not even enter the inner most "for loop" , no quadruplets will get generated , hence $A \times B \times C \times D = \{\}$ : not quadruplets at all.
$P = A \times B \times C \times D$ will have $4 \times 2 \times 1 \times 0 = 0$ elements
Check out :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Can you use English below each statement please to describe to a math novice like myself?  :)

"The Cartesian product of sets $A$ and $B$ is the set of all possible ordered pairs $(x,y)$, such that $x$ is an element of set $A$ and $y$ is an element of set $B$". The English translations of the other two statements differ from this only in the number of sets from which the Cartesian product is formed.

Correct , @H.sapiensrex , I have "attached" a few Examples too.

Is it wrong in mathematics to use real variable names for patterns?  So rather than A, B, C, D, we use the column name(s) in my example instead?

Nothing wrong with using Column Names , that will just take more typing with longer "wordier" lines. It is easier writing $S \times C \times M$ , @JustBeingHelpful , rather than $Shape \times Colour \times Material$ , though that is not wrong.
